# SearchBar data binding with Source not working

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a searchBar in .NET MAUI project and having an issue with its SearchCommand. I am binding this SearchCommand to a method in "ClientsViewMode" which is different from a binding context that the corresponding xaml.cs has, but the method is not being called.

In xaml,

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Realizer.ViewModels">
 ...
 <Grid>
  <VerticalStackLayout>
   <SearchBar SearchCommand="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ClientsViewModel}}, Path=SearchClientsCommand}"
              SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference NameSearchBar}}"
              x:Name="NameSearchBar"/>
  </VerticalStackLayout>
 </Grid>
...
</ContentPage>
```

In xaml.cs,

```
public partial class NewVisitPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly HistoryViewModel _viewModel;
    private readonly ClientsViewModel _clientsViewModel;

    public NewVisitPage(HistoryViewModel viewModel, ClientsViewModel clientsViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;     
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _clientsViewModel = clientsViewModel;
    }

    void NameSearchBar_TextChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.OldTextValue) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            _clientsViewModel.SearchClientsCommand.Execute(null);
            var results = _clientsViewModel.Clients;
            resultList.ItemsSource = results;
        }
    }
}
```

(Although I instantiate "ClientsViewModel" here, it should have nothing to do with this issue because I'm only using this for `NameSearchBar_TextChanged` method within this file.)

In ClientsViewModel

```
 public partial class ClientsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
...
   [RelayCommand]
   private async Task SearchClients(string searchTerm)..
...
}
```

I use this way of accessing a method outside of the binding context in other command properties and they work with no problem. But only this one does not call the method. What am I doing wrong?

There is nothing shown in the XAML Binding Failures tab.

When I select "SaveClientsCommand" and "go to its definition", it shows a auto-generated file, but does not call the method when it runs.

Comment: Do you mean that `SearchClientsCommand` is not included in the view model of current page?

Comment: @Ch1h0 Please show more of your code as it's not entirely clear what your setup is. Please show where and how you set the `BindingContext` and where the `ClientsViewModel` comes in.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I am not sure if I understood your question right, but when I press enter key or tap the search button on soft keyboard on Android emulator, this `SearchCommand` does not call `SearchClientsCommand`. I'm not sure what is wrong with this `SearchCommand="{Binding Source=...}"` line for data binding.

Comment: Please check the answer I posted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting SearchCommmand property in xaml.cs file. In this way, I was able to access `SearchClientsCommand` in ClientsViewModel without redefining this command in HistoryViewModel.

In xaml,

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Realizer.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:HistoryViewModel">
 ...
 <Grid>
  <VerticalStackLayout>
   <SearchBar x:Name="NameSearchBar"
              TextChanged="NameSearchBar_TextChanged"/>
  </VerticalStackLayout>
 </Grid>
...
</ContentPage>
```

In xaml.cs

```
public partial class historyPage : ContentPage
{
  private readonly HistoryViewModel _viewModel;
  private readonly ClientsViewModel _clientsViewModel

  public historyPage(HistoryViewModel viewModel, ClientsViewModel clientsViewModel){
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel;
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    _clientsViewModel = clientsViewModel;
    NameSearchBar.SearchCommand _clientsViewModel.SearchClientsCommand;
  }
                       
  void NameSearchBar_TextChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NameSearchBar.SearchCommandParameter = e.NewTextValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.OldTextValue) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            _clientsViewModel.SearchClientsCommand.Execute(null);
            var results = _clientsViewModel.Clients;
            resultList.ItemsSource = results;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem was that the ClientsViewModel was not the parent of HistoryViewModel.

The other places where I successfully used `Source={x:RelativeSource...` as I mentioned were inside of `<DataTemplate>` where I had a different dataType only within the object and I still had the same view model defined on top of the xaml file like this:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Realizer.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:ClientsViewModel">
 ...
 <Grid>
  <CollectionView>
     ...
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Client">
          ...
          <ImageButton ...
                       Command="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ClientsViewModel}}, Path=ButtonClickedCommand"}/>
          ...
       </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  </CollectionView>
   
...
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is wrong, should be to the bindingcontext of the view, not the viewmodel by itslef.

SearchCommand="{Binding BindingContext.SearchClientsCommand, Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:ClientsView}}}"

Comment: Please format your answer properly, especially the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `AncestorType` of `SearchCommand` from `ClientsViewModel` to `HistoryViewModel`.

```
<SearchBar SearchCommand="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:HistoryViewModel }}, Path=SearchClientsCommand}"
              SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference NameSearchBar}}"
              x:Name="NameSearchBar"/>
```

Note:

We should bind the `command` from the `BindingContext` of current page.
Since you set the `BindingContext` to `HistoryViewModel`,so you need to make sure that the `SearchClientsCommand` is in class `HistoryViewModel.cs`.

```
   public NewVisitPage(HistoryViewModel viewModel, ClientsViewModel clientsViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel;     
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    _clientsViewModel = clientsViewModel;
}
```

Comment: Would something like this `SearchCommand="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ClientsViewModel}}, Path=SearchClientsCommand}"` be unsupported operation? I've seen some people using this line to bind data from multiple sources, and I use this format to access methods that are not in `BindingContext` many other places in my code. This is the only one that is not working.
Do I still need to define `SearchClientsCommand` in BindingContext? If so, there will be the same codes that exist in multiple files, which I don't want and is not pretty.

Comment: Usually, we will use the properties and commands in the view model of current page.  Of course, if the `ClientsViewModel ` is the parent of `HistoryViewModel `, we can do like  this. For more information,please check : [Bind to an ancestor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0#bind-to-an-ancestor).

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy with something else. I've just posted a solution that worked. Thank you for your advice.